# Pandas pd.to_datetime doesn't work due to several cells with different format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have table that is ismilar to this one:

```
          name        date                   value ....
0         Lorenzo     30/11/2019 23:06:14     43
1         Licros      29/11/2019 22:01:34     25
2         Feldik      29/11/2019 22:05:32     57
...
1183400   Alexis      01/12/2021              43
1183401   Sandra      02/12/2021              79
```

As you can see, i nthe same  date column, I have some values that are date+time and some are only date.
I want t ochange the type of all the observations to be datetime, if they have hour then to be datetime with hour and if they don't have the hour, to have only date.

AT tge beginning I have tried this:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

but that gave me an error from the time part of the string:

> ValueError: time data '22/02/2020' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)

Then I tried to change the format to not include the time, just the date:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

But that gives me the opposite error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  23:06:14

**Is there any simple way to convert this column to datetime,  despite it has two  different "length" of data (date or date+time).**

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`?

Comment: but then how can I make sure that it doesn't mismatch the date with month?

Comment: Add `dayfirst=True` - `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)`